# Derivative is an alternating 1-tensor?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, exterior-algebra

I am reading through spivak, and he states, if $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then $Df(p): \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$, and since this is linear, we have that $Df(p) \in \Lambda^1(\mathbb{R^n})$. I don't follow this exactly, I know that since it is linear, $Df(p) \in \mathcal{J}^1(\mathbb{R^n})$, but I don't see how it is alternating.

Comment: What does "alternating" mean specifically for $1$-tensors?

Comment: One tensor doesn't even see the condition $v \wedge w = w \wedge v$, which is a condition that only starts making sense for wedge of 2 or more tensors. (If you think of the exterior algebra as a quotient of the tensor algebra by some homogeneous ideal generated in degree 2, then the intersection of this ideal with the degree 1 part is 0.)

Comment: This is what I don't follow: I have, for $T \in \mathcal{J^k}(V)$, if$T(v_1,...,v_i,...,v_j,...,v_n) = -T(v_1,..,v_j,...,v_i,...,v_n)$ then $T$ is an alternating tensor. I just don't see how a 1-tensor is alternating at all, as $\mathcal{J^1}(V) = V^{\star}$, all we have is linearity.

Comment: A $1$-tensor is _vacuously_ alternating. The condition for alternating says "for any $i\neq j$, something, something...", and a $1$-tensor fulfills this because there are no such $i,j$, and thus it cannot _not_ be alternating.

Comment: @Arthur could you expand on it more? if we have $f \in V^{\star}$, then you are saying $f(v_1,...,v_i,...,v_j,...,v_n) = -f(v_1,...,v_j,...,v_i,...v_n)$?

Comment: @lampj20la You have too many $v$'s in there. A tensor $T \in \mathcal J^k(V)$ is a function $V^k \to \Bbb R$. So, if $T$ is a $2$-tensor, then it takes two vectors, say $v_1$ and $v_2$, and it returns a number, say $r$. We write this as $T(v_1, v_2) = r$. If it so happens that for any vectors $v_1, v_2$ we have $T(v_1, v_2) = -T(v_2,v_1)$, then we call $T$ alternating. A $1$-tensor $f$ is just a function $f:V \to \Bbb R$, so the corresponfing way to write that would be $f(v)=r$. There is nothing to alternate in there, and by convension we call it alternating (since it's not _not_ alternating).

Comment: Note that higher derivative tensors are symmetric, and therefore most certainly not alternating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T\in \mathcal J^k(V)$ is a $k$-tensor, then it is a function that takes as input $k$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in V$ and gives back a number $r\in \Bbb R$. We say that $T$ is *alternating* if for *any* such vectors and any $i,j$ with $1\leq i<j\leq k$ we have
$$
T(v_1,\ldots,v_i,\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_k)=-T(v_1,\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_i,\ldots,v_k)
$$Now if $f$ is a $1$-tensor, then it fulfills the alternating property *vacuously*: in order for $f$ to not be alternating, there must be $i,j$ with corresponding $v_i$ and $v_j$ that makes a "witness" to $f$ not alternating. But we can't have $1\leq i<j\leq 1$. Therefore there is no witness, and $f$ is alternating.